# I defined i to be 2, then i loop i = i * i; but after 6 lines/prints, it turns to 0

Tags: c#, while-loop

```
int i = 2;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    i = i * i;
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

For some reason it prints:

```
2
4
16
256
65536
0
0
0
0
```

Why? I also tried `i *= i`, but that didn't work either (same output).

Comment: Did you try making `i` a `long`?

Comment: Max int is ?? Try int32 (won't work - see answers)

Comment: @NickA didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`65,536 * 65,536 = 4,294,967,296`

but the maximum value of int is `2,147,483,647`

Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int

to get a few more iterations you can use `BigInteger`

```
System.Numerics.BigInteger i = 2;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    i = i * i;
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

Comment: Well, at least, this doesn't seem to have limits (a part from the growing slowness after each iteration)

Answer (score 1):

An integer maximum value is 2,147,483,647. 65536 * 65536 is equal to 4,294,967,296. This value can't be saved in an integer, thus leading to the 0 value you are seeing here. You can try to change the type of `i` to be able to store bigger numbers (long, double...) to delay this issue, but you will always end up reaching a limit and having a 0 result.

Comment: The suggestion to use a long will delay the problem for just one more loop

Comment: Changing to a long allowed i to become bigger, but still ended up as 0. Thanks for explaining though.

Answer (score 0):

65536*65536=2^32.

Now int is calculated mod 2^32, or, in other words the value of an int is equivalent to the value of the remainder when the 'real' number is divided by 2^32. (It also wraps around at 2^31, so between 2^31 and 2^32 it will be negative).

In this case the remainder is 0, so the int will be 0. Then when you square it again, it is equal to 0*0 =0, so it remains 0.

If you want you can add a reference to System.Numerics and use the BigInteger class:

```
        System.Numerics.BigInteger i = 2;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            i = i * i;
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
```

Will work till you run out of memory. The BigInteger class can store arbitrarily large integers.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `int` type with `long` as `65,536 * 65,536 = 4,294,967,296` and that exceeds the capacity of int type.

```
long i = 2;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        i = i * i;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
```

Comment: The suggestion to use a long will delay the problem for just one more loop

Comment: I don't know when his loop will stop, it's an infinite loop, I think we need more info of what exactly the problem is!